# How to set Default Dialer for functions under test?

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-dialer

I know from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged, that you can set the default dialer by having the necessary items in your manifest and permissions listed. One of those being the Dial intent.

What i'm trying to do is build a library that does all of these content provider calls and provide a nice reactive way of doing things to my application. While building the library I would like to add some integration tests around these device calls.

There's the GrantPermissionsRule that helps with setting permissions already defined in your manifest but how does one deal with becoming the default dialer or SMS application? I'd accept even an adb command that you could run using a Runtime execute command.

I also tried testing on an emulator and I noticed that you can give your app WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS but not MANAGE_USERS which is the other necessary permission you need if you were to use reflection to access the https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telecomm/java/android/telecom/DefaultDialerManager.java

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try adb command:

```
adb shell settings put secure dialer_default_application com.google.android.dialer
```

replacing com.google.android.dialer with your package.